# What is the impact of using React hooks in NextJS SSR?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, server-side-rendering

I am building a server-side rendered webpage using NextJS Page Router. I am having trouble finding reliable documentation on the impact of using React's client-side hooks in an server-side rendered page.

If I've defined a `getServerSideProps` method, and use this method to get **all** of the data I need to populate the page, is there any reason to avoid using `useState` to manipulate the UI? All I'm trying to do is show and hide something when the user clicks a button.

My primary concern is SEO. I've read that `useEffect` will cause the page to be rendered client-side, but is this limitation also true for `useState`?